# MVC pattern in R

Tags: javascript, html, r, model-view-controller

I am new to R and I need to develop a web app in R and have to create a login page and a private zone. I use shiny. The problem is that I have researched a lot on github, shiny site and google and the only tutorial I have been able to find is this one http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/authentication-and-database.html. But the thing  is that it uses an ui.r for the interface and I want to be flexible and build it in HTML.

Is there any framework or library or tutorial I can use to build a web app following an MVC pattern, at least, to create a login page and a private zone (all in HTML)? And, above all, be able to load different HTML pages depending if the user has logged in correctly or not, its permissions and so on.

**EDIT**

I have just read that:

*Each R process can only run a single Shiny app. Each Shiny app is only designed to run a single page. (Although some people e.g. Vincent Nijs have experimented with multiple HTML files with a single server.R)*

*One solution is to try to redesign your app to be a single page that switches through different "modes" (you could use tabsetPanel or get fancier with JavaScript, and some other people here like Vincent have implemented navbars).*

So it may be possible.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of shiny is that, although it allows flexibility and can incorporate custom HTML, it is specifically designed for those who are not full stack web developers (e.g. me). Therefore it may not meet your preference for control.

I would recommend checking out [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/) as a means to integrate R into your framework of preference.

From their website:

> OpenCPU is a system for embedded scientific computing and reproducible
>   research. The OpenCPU server provides a reliable and interoperable
>   HTTP API for data analysis based on R. You can either use the public
>   servers or host your own.

Answer (score 0):

to follow the MVC architecture as ASP.NET MVC for example, I think it is not available in shiny, but you can structure your app to a set of modules and after that, you can send and receive data across these modules as you want.

- here an example to make a custom HTML page and reference it in your shiny app

1. Your custom index HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- template.html -->
    <html>
      <head>
        {{ headContent() }}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          {{ button }}
          {{ slider }}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

2. ui.R file in your shiny app

```html
 htmlTemplate("template.html",
      button = actionButton("action", "Action"),
      slider = sliderInput("x", "X", 1, 100, 50)
    )
```

3. references

- [shiny_rstudio](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html)

I have found a very interesting package you can use to help you as you build more complex apps using shiny its name is a [golem](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem)